# Conditionally render label line in Recharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

Im trying to render a label **line** conditionally in a Piechart in Recharts library.
Currently, the label line is being render absolutely for all sections of the Piechart.
My goal is to set a condition to render it if, for example, the % of the section is higher the X.

The docs are no really clear about it and do not provide clear examples

```
If false set, label lines will not be drawn. 
If true set, label lines will be drawn which have the props calculated internally. 
If object set, label lines will be drawn which have the props mergered by the internal calculated props and the option.
If ReactElement set, the option can be the custom label line element. 
If set a function, the function will be called to render customized label line.
```

I was thinking about something in the sort of:

```
      <Pie
        data={data}
        cx={200}
        cy={200}
        labelLine={data=> data.value > 0.5}
        dataKey="value"
      >
      </Pie>
```